# Partitions on a TF card are not working as expected; third partition is not seen

Tags: linux, partitioning, filesystems

I want to create three partition in a new brand TF card (not micro SD), but I can't sort it out! What I did up to now:

1. create a disk partition table

   ```
   fdisk -l /dev/sdd
   Disco /dev/sdd: 250 GiB, 268436504576 bytes, 524290048 sectores
   Modelo de disco: USB SD Reader   
   Unidades: sectores de 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
   Tamaño de sector (lógico/físico): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
   Tamaño de E/S (mínimo/óptimo): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
   Tipo de etiqueta de disco: dos
   Identificador del disco: 0xf7620d53

   Disposit.  Inicio Comienzo     Final  Sectores Tamaño Id Tipo
   /dev/sdd1  *          2048   8194047   8192000   3,9G  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
   /dev/sdd2          8194048  16386047   8192000   3,9G 83 Linux
   /dev/sdd3         16386048 524290047 507904000 242,2G  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
   ```
2. Make the filesystem:

   ```
   mkfs.fat -n ANBERNIC /dev/sdd1
   mkfs.ext4 -L SHARE /dev/sdd2
   mkfs.fat -n GAMES /dev/sdd3
   ```

no errors thrown

3. But the last partition doesn't appear!

   ```
   lsblk -f
   sdd                                                                              
   ├─sdd1 vfat   FAT32 ANBERNIC 6E52-6C60                                           
   ├─sdd2 ext4   1.0   SHARE    6de8cf4f-be99-4c17-9c1d-22228dd8c450                
   └─sdd3
   ```

What I am doing wrong? Can't TF cards have more than 2 partitions?

[edit]
More details about what @Kamil asked:

```
# file -skr /dev/sdd3
/dev/sdd3: data

# mount /dev/sdd3 /mnt
mount: /mnt: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdd3,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
       dmesg(1) may have more information after failed mount system call.

# dmesg |tail
[30621.365113] FAT-fs (sdd3): bogus number of reserved sectors
[30621.365119] FAT-fs (sdd3): Can't find a valid FAT filesystem
[30621.367010] XFS (sdd3): Invalid superblock magic number
```

I have also tried to make a ext4 filesystem in /dev/sdd3 (just to try something), with the same result:

```
# mkfs.ext4 -L GAMES /dev/sdd3
...

# file -skr /dev/sdd3
/dev/sdd3: data

# mount /dev/sdd3 /mnt
mount: /mnt: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdd3,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
       dmesg(1) may have more information after failed mount system call.

# dmesg |tail
[31413.748671] EXT4-fs (sdd3): VFS: Can't find ext4 filesystem
[31413.750915] FAT-fs (sdd3): bogus number of reserved sectors
[31413.750924] FAT-fs (sdd3): Can't find a valid FAT filesystem
[31413.753555] XFS (sdd3): Invalid superblock magic number
```

In this last case, I am still more puzzled, because I don't understand the two lines with "FAT-fs"...

---

#### Edit2:

```
# cp /bin/bash /dev/sdd3; echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches; cmp /bin/bash /dev/sdd3
/bin/bash /dev/sdd3 differ: byte 1, línea 1

# ls -l /dev/sdd*
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 48 Dec 10 13:43 /dev/sdd
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 49 Dec 10 13:43 /dev/sdd1
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 50 Dec 10 13:43 /dev/sdd2
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 51 Dec 10 13:53 /dev/sdd3
```

I have also tried testdisk, as said in post
[FAT filesystem - bad superblock](https://superuser.com/questions/593792/fat-filesystem-bad-superblock) but without results :-(

Comment: (1) What is the output of `file -skr /dev/sdd3`? (2) What happens when you try to `mount /dev/sdd3 somewhere`?

Comment: You wrote "the last partition doesn't appear" and then posted the output of `lsblk -f` where it does appear. What doesn't appear is information about the filesystem, I understand this is the issue. IMO the question should be rephrased. Partitions and filesystems are different concepts, the third partition itself is seen.

Comment: You are right, my problem is that I have a partition (the 3rd) which does not "accept" a filesystem, or if it does, the filesystem doesn't appear.

Comment: Please write some not-too-small file to `/dev/sdd3`, flush cache, read anew and compare. E.g. `cp /bin/bash /dev/sdd3; echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches; cmp /bin/bash /dev/sdd3` . If you get "EOF in /bin/bash" then it's OK. If you get "files differ" then it probably means the card only pretends you can write to this area; it may be faulty or bogus.

Comment: Also please post the output of `ls -l /dev/sdd*`. This is a sanity check.

Comment: Most likely the card has failed or its size is a fake.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski, very possible, OP should use one of the various fake flash drive checkers, like https://fight-flash-fraud.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html

Comment: I agree that the TF card might be smaller than the seller says, but in any case, I think it is bigger than 8 GB, so the third partition should be at least 100 MB, if not more... It is an unresolved mistery, so I will mark the post as "closed".

Comment: @seirov Please do not self tag something as “(closed)”. That is not the way this site works. If you feel this question is not valid, delete it. Otherwise, please let this question stand as-is; you never know if someone at a later date can provide an answer.